# Nodejs grunt obfuscate

Tags: node.js, obfuscation

I'm using Nodejs grunt module. I know grunt min option minifies a files. But now I need to obfuscate files like google closure compiler. Does grunt have that feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The grunt min task allows you to set UglifyJS (the grunt min tool) options, which can give you greater control on how the destination file is mangled and compressed.

https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/blob/master/docs/task_min.md#specifying-uglifyjs-options

https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

from the grunt task_min doc:

```
Specifying UglifyJS options

In this example, custom UglifyJS mangle, squeeze and codegen options are
specified. The listed methods and their expected options are explained in
the API section of the UglifyJS documentation:

The mangle object is passed into the pro.ast_mangle method.
The squeeze object is passed into the pro.ast_squeeze method.
The codegen object is passed into the pro.gen_code method.

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
  min: {
    dist: {
      src: ['dist/built.js'],
      dest: 'dist/built.min.js'
    }
  },
  uglify: {
    mangle: {toplevel: true},
    squeeze: {dead_code: false},
    codegen: {quote_keys: true}
  }
});
```