# obfuscating whole phonegap angularjs project (all my javascript files)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, obfuscation

I see many obfuscators which always obfuscate only one independed js file.
In my phonegap angularjs project I have many js files (controllers, factories, services) that are in separate files and depends on each other. 
Is there a software that will obfuscate all my js files, so that it will not break files that depend on each other?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use grunt and uglify: [Nodejs grunt obfuscate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669104/nodejs-grunt-obfuscate)

For AngularJS specifically, make sure you read the "Note on minification". You may need to slightly change the way you inject dependencies to avoid them being breaking during obfuscation: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

Comment: I could say obfuscation is diferent than minification proccess. And grunt obfuscate is not for angular projects, is for node projects.