# Hybrid Mobile App Security

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, security, hybrid-mobile-app

in my case i have an **Hybrid Mobile App** with Cordova.

How can I avoid changes to my **javascript/AngularJs** if someone download my *.apk or *.ipa and try to use it with a browser ?

I want to encrypt my source javascript code or if possible want to full content in *.apk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to avoid other person make changes in your code is minify and obfuscate the javascript files.

[Here](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) you can test it by yorself.

But if you want to minify all the javascipt files of your project, i suggest you to use some task runner like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) with [Uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify).

To avoid unwanted requests you have to configure Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) in your server.

Comment: My javascript is minify but if u use minfy javascript in Chrome, he 
align the code and u can see my url webservices, ecc

Comment: To avoid unwanted requests to your web service you should configure
Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) in your server

Comment: I use Grunt with Uglify for minify my javascript, 
how can I Obfuscate my code ?

Comment: i think you can find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669104/nodejs-grunt-obfuscate "here")

Comment: Ok thanks, but this doesn't resolve my problem, because i have a solution with many files in AngularJS and if i try minify all it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

While most people will agree that Javascript encryption is not a fool-proof method, there are a few cases where increasing the efforts required and slowing down the attacker often helps.  You can check tools like [refresh-sf](https://refresh-sf.com/), Uglify and also [obfuscator.io](https://obfuscator.io/) for code obfuscation. However, basic encryption and obfuscation practices don’t prevent people from lifting and using your code, and considering the advanced cyber-attacks happening these days, hackers already have a way around such practices.

My suggestion would be to invest in mobile application security tools like Arxan, AppSealing, or Appdome to apply a robust security architecture on your application. Having personally used AppSealing, I can say that they have regular updates and definitely keep you guarded from the latest attacks. Their framework is integrated directly in your apk so there’s no additional coding required. I would suggest you look for such mobile app security solutions for a more robust security architecture. I am sure there must be more solutions apart from the ones I have mentioned above. Just research and pick the one that suits your requirement and budget.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all minify all your js file into one single bundle.js and use cordova-anti-tampering plugin. if somebody tries to tamper your apk and rebuild the apk app will get crashed.
2. This plugin will create hash value for all the files. if you want to secure your app more You can store these hashvalues to server once and check your files hash values with server stored hash values.